# How to horizontally align select boxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I align the following select boxes immediately horizontally besides each other.

Thats Expiry date: month:year

//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

http://jsfiddle.net/fzVm8/

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline" for="expirymonth" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Expiry Date </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select id="expmonth" ng-model="expirymonth" ng-change="setcardmonth(expirymonth)" ng-options="e.month for e in cardmonth"/>
                    <select style="margin-left: 200px" ng-model="expiryyear" id="expyear" ng-change="setcardyear(expiryyear)" ng-options="y.year for y in cardyear"/>
                    </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the label class to checkbox-inline.